# Что предлагает IntelliJ Idea или Android Studio по Alt-Enter?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

В документации я нашел, что по Alt-Enter Android Studio предлагает следующие варианты:

1. Результаты [Code Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/code-inspection.html) и предложения по улучшению
2. Предложения [Intention Actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/intention-actions.html)

Но есть еще группа предложений, которые не являются ни тем, ни другим. Например, когда я пишу присваивание еще не определенной переменной.

[image: скриншот из студии, var не определена]

Что это за звери, где про них почитать, и можно ли их настраивать?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это как раз Intention Action и судя по цвету лампочки Quickfix suggested

Comment: Вроде бы похоже, но есть сомнения. Intention Actions можно выключать, а эти нельзя. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/disabling-intention-actions.html И я не могу найти этот экшен в списк в настройках. Может быть я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Никогда не задумывался над этим, но я думаю, что самым быстрым и самым правильным выходом будет спросить у создателей IDEA. Там отличные люди работают - они будут рады помочь.

Comment: разве это не инспекция undefinded field ?

Comment: @pavlofff Я тоже так думал сначала. Но если руками запустить инспекцию, то в списке найденных проблем про эту переменную не будет ни слова, но зато будет про менее значимые проблемы, вроде неиспользуемых полей и лишних импортов. Из этого делаю вывод, что это не инспекция. Идеи? https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnontkd49bawa8k/Screenshot%202017-01-09%2012.35.14.png?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

Поддержка ответила, что это все-таки Intention Actions, но захардкоженные, поэтому в настройках их не видно, и выключить нельзя.

> It's Intention Action since Alt+Enter is a shortcut for Show Intention Actions. Some of them are hardcoded and cannot be disabled.

(https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000018730-What-origin-of-suggesiton-)